# Generate Type Library (TLB) from a Header File

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, typelib

Is it possible to generate type library (.tlb) by using either a header file (.h) or lib (.lib) file?

H file: http://codepad.org/XzBgp9In

IDL generated from H file: http://codepad.org/6IWmuWmx

Error while compiling IDL to TLB:

out\DbgEng.idl(202) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "_Out_writes_bytes_"

out\DbgEng.idl(202) : error MIDL2026 : cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation

Comment: You compile IDL into TLB. Having H in front of you, you can manually re-create IDL, however I doubt there is a tool for this. LIB is not helpful.

Comment: I do have a script that converts .H to .IDL, but when I try to generate TLB from IDL I get type error.

Comment: So show us the IDL and tell us what the error is.

Comment: Updated files. Please check line 202 in IDL file.

Comment: You produce invalid IDL - too many errors there to even comment specific ones.

Comment: You are to approach this one: [DbgEng.idl](https://code.google.com/p/wbts-runner/source/browse/trunk/wbts-runner/runner/third_party/buggery/DbgEng.idl?r=3)